# What caption certification should I use for my YouTube video that contains parts from an anime and a movie?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

The video I want to upload on YouTube contains parts and background music themes from an anime and a movie. I will also turn off monetization for my video. I absolutely do not want to earn a single bit of money from my video.

What caption certification should I use for my video? I am not talking about language captions.

Which of the caption certifications listed below should I use for my video?

1. None
2. This content has never aired on television in the U.S.
3. This content has only aired on television in the U.S. without captions
4. This content has not aired on U.S. television with captions since September 30, 2012.
5. This content does not fall within a category of online programming that requires captions under FCC regulations (47 C.F.R. § 79).
6. The FCC and/or U.S. Congress has granted an exemption from captioning requirements for this content.

Please help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't include enough details and requires knowledge about copyright and publishing media including third-party-created content. It might be on topic on [video.se], or [law.se]. You might ask for a site recommendation on [meta.se].